# How to show network signal strength in dbm in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

> Just wanted to show the signal strength in dbm in flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this plugin **[internet_speed](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test)** to get speed of internet and  use these values to show in your UI.

Comment: it is deprecated now is there any other way?

Comment: how can we show the network strength in dbs using this?

Comment: Nop, this is for bandwidth, not signal strength...